# Transparent image is not being transparent when used in modal

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to append a modal that will only consist of a transparent gif. It is unfortunately not being displayed with transparent background. There is no problem with gifs transparency. I am trying to make a loading screen with a black background and transparent gif. Here is my css class for my modal :

```
.v--modal-overlay[data-modal="loading"] {
  background: black;
}
```

Modals html (I am using vue-js-modal library by the way) :

```
<modal name="loading" width="256px" height="256px">
          <img src="../../public/loading.gif" />
        </modal>
```

I have anticipated it to look like this : [image]

But instead, got this one with a white background:
[image]

Comment: Try setting `modal{background:transparent;}` or show your complete working code please

Answer (score 1):

```css
.bg_black {
  background: #000;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg_black img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_black">
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/17mNCcKU1mJlrbXodo/giphy.gif">
</div>
```

You should know that you have to put a transparent background of your gif so you achieve your output.